# Can a Canadian get a US extended travel visa?

Tags: visas, canadian-citizens, long-term

Can a retired Canadian citizen get an an extended travel visa to the USA? If so, for how long would it be, a year or two ?

Answer (score 1):

You can get a long term multiple entry travel visa  (up to ten years) however note that regardless of the duration of the visa, you will only be allowed to stay in the USA for maximum six months per visit.

We do not have the equivalent of the [Canadian Super Visa](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/visit-canada/parent-grandparent-super-visa/eligibility.html).

Comment: It might also be worth noting that because most Canadians do not need a visa to enter the US for up to six months per visit, getting the visa that you mention brings absolutely no benefit to most Canadians.

Comment: It might also be worth noting that visitors can actually be admitted for up to 1 year instead of the usual six months. However, I don't know what circumstances would allow such a period of admission, and I suppose a person in OP's circumstances might not be able to qualify.

Comment: Thank you for your responses..as I wanted to travel across the USA..now am doing it 6 months at a time then go back to Canada  was hoping I could do this for a full year.. rather then going back and forth.. so I am guessing that getting the extended travel visa won't be the answer.. Thank you for responding